representing matrix operations involving element wise multiplication
I have a vector $y$ of dimensions $t\times 1$
I have another matrix $x$ of dimension $t\times n$
I want to get a matrix $z$ of dimension $t\times n$ such that $z_{a,b} = x_{a,b} * y_a $
I then want to get the matrix $f$ of $n\times n$ dimensions which is the product of z with itself transposed so $f = z^Tz $
Is there a way to write $f$ and $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ ?

Let $\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}\odot$ denote the Hadamard product
and $w$ the all-ones vector of size $(n\times{\tt1})$, then
$$\eqalign{
&Z=X\odot yw^T \
&F = \LR{wy^T\odot X^T} \LR{X\odot yw^T}
}$$
This choice of $w$ corresponds to multiplication via broadcasting in many computer languages. If you're not trying to replicate that operation, then $w$ can be any vector of length $n.;$
